# FB share SDK not working - only displays stock app photo

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, share

I am using the following code to share my page on FB.  The data-title, data-desc, and data-image do not share.  When the dialog link pops up, FB only shows the app default photo.  When it is shared, the href correctly shares and the app default photo is displayed.

Code is below and I am also pasting my head (with og tags) at the bottom of the script. Is there a conflict there? Is FB failing to read my php tags?

Any help is appreciated.

html:

```
<li><div id="fb-root"></div>
<a class="fb_share" href="<?php echo JO_Request::getInstance()->getFullUrl(); ?>"  data-image="" data-title="<?php echo $this->mypage['postTitle']; ?>" data-desc="<?php echo $this->mypage['postDesc'] ? nl2br(substr($this->mypage['postDesc'], 0, 200)) . '...' : ''; ?>" data-width="450"><img src="https://www.mygoodness.com/date/myimage.png" alt="" width="20" height="20"></a></li>
```

script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'app id',
            secret: 'app secret',
            status: true,
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true
        });
    };

    (function(d, debug)
    {var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document, /*debug*/ false));

    function postToFeed(title, desc, url, image) {
        FB.XFBML.parse();
        var obj = {method: 'feed',link: url, picture: image,name: title,description: desc};
        function callback(response) {}
        FB.ui(obj, callback);
    }

    var fbShareBtn = document.querySelector('.fb_share');
    fbShareBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var title = fbShareBtn.getAttribute('data-title'),
            desc = fbShareBtn.getAttribute('data-desc'),
            url = fbShareBtn.getAttribute('href'),
            image = fbShareBtn.getAttribute('data-image');
        postToFeed(title, desc, url, image);

        return false;
    });

</script>
```

head:

```
<head prefix="og:http://ogp.me/ns# fb:http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">

    <!-- Meta -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=echo,chrome=1">

    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="app id">
    <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo JO_Request::getInstance()->getFullUrl(); ?>">
    <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $this->mypage['postTitle']; ?>">
    <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $this->baseUrl;?>myhome.png">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
    <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $this->mypage['postDesc'] ? nl2br(substr($this->mypage['postDesc'], 0, 200)) . '...' : ''; ?>">

</head>
```

Comment: The script code need to be inner body, that's recommend fb

Comment: @RuiCosta Thanks Rui. You mean set the code right after the    --    <a class="fb_share"   ---  line?

Comment: yes, if not work, post capture of console log errors

Comment: @RuiCosta Sorry, that didn't work.  And there are no console error logs.  The sharing works, it just shares the wrong things.  BTW, the href shares correctly.  The data-title and data-desc and data-iimage do not share.

Comment: wait, you server is localhost or not?

Comment: @RuiCosta I have it on localhost and on a regular server. Try to share the following page on FB to see the behavior - https://kuttlefish.com/blog/blogPost?blognumber=2

Comment: Facebook server apparently read your page and you have commented `<!-- -->`the line `<meta property="og:image"` need to remove the comment tags

Comment: Tx @RuiCosta, that still didn't fix the problem. If you scrape the page, you will see that there is still an error but if you scrape another page, kuttlefish.com/blog/blogPost?blognumber=2, you will see there are no errors but that the big image still is the only thing that displays. I think it has something to do with the php data I am sharing but can't figure it out.

Comment: already solved the problem?

Comment: Hi @RuiCosta, Sorry, I am traveling so just seeing your comment.  No, I have not solved this problem; however, I think the issue is how FB scrapes my page - I think it is using a scraped image and not the metatags I define. If you try sharing from this page: kuttlefish.com/blog/blogPost?blognumber=2, you will see it only displays the photo on your FB page. In another place on my site, e.g. https://kuttlefish.com/items/geek-earrings-christmas-key-keyboard-circuit-gift-for-anniversary-beige-hip, you will see the same issue persists. Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @RuiCosta Actually, if you try downloading my image. you will see the size conforms to FB dimensions. It is confusing. I actually think the issue has to do with sharing my php variables from the page. If I substitute my php variables in the og tags with text, then the post displays correctly. But I just don't know what the issue is.  Perhaps I need different header script tags?  Tx for your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Well actually your tags are properly implemented, the problem is that the image that you set to display in the dialog box to share exece the limit set in open space graph. (max limit-8mb)

Czech documentation for open graph tags that can implement web.
[Sharing Open Graph Webmaster Guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup)

You can also examine your links with this debugger for open graph, I think you will be most useful.
[Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/)